# Unable to configure EMDK version 7.4.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio, barcode-scanner

I have tried [this](https://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-android/7-4/guide/setup/) link but when I add it's dependency it fails to find out this. I don't understand the reason as I am following the steps in the mentioned URL.

I have tried the following dependencies one by one but non of these works

```
compileOnly 'com.symbol:emdk:x.x.x'
compileOnly 'com.symbol:emdk:7.4.0'
compileOnly 'com.symbol:emdk:v7.4.0'
compileOnly 'com.symbol:emdk:7.4+'
```

Comment: Hi, why do you insist on using the [zebra] tag? Have you read its description and what it is intended to be used for?

Answer (score 2):

At last i just found a solution simply a

```
implementation 'com.symbol:emdk:7.4.24'
```

Comment: I would advise against using dynamic versions in gradle dependencies (the + sign) but I agree the documentation could do with improving - I'll pass the feedback to our docs team.  FYI the specific version numbers are available on bintray: https://bintray.com/zebratechnologies/EMDKAndroid/com.symbol.emdk

Comment: I have implemented https://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-android/7-4/tutorial/tutBasicScanningAPI/ but it fails to execute, it gave me an error on EMDKResults results = EMDKManager.getEMDKManager(getApplicationContext(), this);
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: stub

Comment: If you have any solid sample app for getting scanned data from ZEBRA scanner, kindly share that i am using ZEBRA DS2278, i am trying to get the string read by scanner in a variable and want to disable the dataWedge feature, i have also posted a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58552979/want-to-read-scanned-bar-code-from-zebra-ds2278-programmatically-android

Comment: I have answered the question at that link.  Please note that EMDK is not applicable for the DS2278

Answer (score 0):

compileOnly 'com.symbol:emdk:7.6.10'