# Want to read scanned bar code from ZEBRA DS2278 programmatically Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, barcode-scanner

I am trying to read the scanned barcode from ZEBRA device over Bluetooth how can i do it, is there a way like i will subscribe to a characteristic and will get the value scanned from ZEBRA device.

I have used **LightBlue** app and have seen the characteristics but didn't get any solution

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the Zebra Android scanner SDK (https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/developer-tools/scanner-sdk-for-android.html) that download contains a sample app with source code along with the SDK.  Although the DS2278 is not listed amongst the compatible devices I think that is just an accidental omission since the release notes state DS2278 support was added in version 2.0.8